# Create a new layer from objects

Tags: qgis

I want to "put together" single objects of a layer (shapefile) in order to create a new layer out of the already selected objects.

In my case, I work with a shapefile of Mexico that shows its States (estados) and I want to select a few states, make a new layer out of those states and visualize them in another colour.

Answer (score 1):

To make a new layer from selected attributes, you can right click on the shapefile and go to save as new layer. The will promt you to a interface where you can save the selected attributes as NEW SHAPEFILE.

Comment: Thank you! How do I right click a shapefile? In the layer view I can only select or right click layers